# How to instantiate a WebSocketAdapter instance for Jetty websockets

Tags: websocket, jetty

I followed the example to create a websocket server:

```
    Server server = new Server();
    ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
    connector.setPort(port);
    server.addConnector(connector);

    ServletContextHandler servletContextHandler = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/", true, false);

    EventServlet es = injector.getInstance(EventServlet.class);
    servletContextHandler.addServlet(new ServletHolder(es), "/events/*");
```

The EventServlet class looks like:

```
    public class EventServlet extends WebSocketServlet {
        @Override
        public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
            factory.getPolicy().setIdleTimeout(10000);
            factory.register(EventSocketCache.class);

        }
    }
```

The EventSocketCache looks like:

```
public class EventSocketCache extends WebSocketAdapter {


private static int i = 0;
private static int counter = 0;

private static Map<Integer, Session> sessionMap = new HashMap<>();

private final Cache<String, String> testCache;

@Inject
public EventSocketCache(Cache<String, String> testCache) {
    this.testCache = testCache;
}

@Override
public void onWebSocketConnect(Session session) {
    super.onWebSocketConnect(session);
    System.out.println("Socket Connected: " + session);
    System.out.println("Connect: " + session.getRemoteAddress().getAddress());
    try {
        session.getRemote().sendString("Hello Webbrowser");
        session.setIdleTimeout(50000);        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void onWebSocketText(String message) {
    super.onWebSocketText(message);
    System.out.println("Received TEXT message: " + message);
}


@Override
public void onWebSocketBinary(byte[] payload, int offset, int len) {
    byte[] newData = Arrays.copyOfRange(payload, offset, offset + len);

    try {
        Common.Success success = Common.Success.parseFrom(newData);
        System.err.println("------> " + success.getIsSuccess());
    } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void onWebSocketClose(int statusCode, String reason) {
    System.err.println("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^");
    // Remove from the list here....
    super.onWebSocketClose(statusCode, reason);
    System.out.println("Socket Closed: [" + statusCode + "] " + reason);
}


@Override
public void onWebSocketError(Throwable cause) {
    System.err.println("######################################");
    super.onWebSocketError(cause);
    cause.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

}

Now when I use my client and send a request, I end up getting:

```
org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException: Didn't switch protocols
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection.validateResponse(UpgradeConnection.java:249)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection.read(UpgradeConnection.java:181)
at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection.onFillable(UpgradeConnection.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:596)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:527)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:63256', transport: 'socket'
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException: Didn't switch protocols
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.FuturePromise.get(FuturePromise.java:123)
    at com.gamecenter.websockets.EventClient.main(EventClient.java:25)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.UpgradeException: Didn't switch protocols
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection.validateResponse(UpgradeConnection.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection.read(UpgradeConnection.java:181)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.io.UpgradeConnection.onFillable(UpgradeConnection.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.run(AbstractConnection.java:358)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:527)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

It seems as there is a problem creating an instance of EventSocketCache; if I don't have the constructor in there, everything works fine.
I'd like to know how to instantiate EventSocketCache properly and register it with EventServlet so things work?

Answer (score 1):

I guess I've found a solution for your problem. You have to use a WebSocketCreator in your WebSocketServlet:

```java
public class MenuServlet extends WebSocketServlet {
@Inject
private Injector injector;

@Override
public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory webSocketServletFactory) {
    // Register your Adapater
    webSocketServletFactory.register(MenuSocket.class);

    // Get the current creator (for reuse)
    final WebSocketCreator creator = webSocketServletFactory.getCreator();

    // Set your custom Creator
    webSocketServletFactory.setCreator(new WebSocketCreator() {
        @Override
        public Object createWebSocket(ServletUpgradeRequest servletUpgradeRequest, ServletUpgradeResponse servletUpgradeResponse) {
            Object webSocket = creator.createWebSocket(servletUpgradeRequest, servletUpgradeResponse);

            // Use the object created by the default creator and inject your members
            injector.injectMembers(webSocket);

            return webSocket;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

there you can inject your members into your WebSocketAdapater. This actually worked for me.

Comment: This helped me when my registered class needs an object an it is the only way to cast my object to the actual class and call the related methods to set some objects, thanks!

Comment: Where do the @Inject and Injector classes come from?